# Global mouse button press capture for Windows alternatives (WH_MOUSE_LL seems to lag the mouse)

Tags: c++, windows, performance, io

I'm having some trouble writing a mouse key listener.

### My goal

The goal is to write a system wide button/key listener, which supports keyboard & mouse button inputs.

Don't worry, this thread is only about the mouse button parts, the keyboard listener works fine.

I'm using this for a push to talk voice gate for my VoIP application.

### My current approach

I'm currently using the `WH_MOUSE_LL` mouse hook, in order to capture mouse events.

In order to achieve the highest performance, for avoiding mouse slow-down, I tried to minimize any bottlenecks.

Currently I'm using this code for the callback method:

```cpp
thread_local KeyboardHook* thread_hook{nullptr};

void KeyboardHook::register_mouse_hook() {
    this->mouse_hook_id = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, _mouse_hook_callback, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), 0);
    if(!this->keyboad_hook_id) {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(this->keyboad_hook_id);
        cerr << "Failed to register mouse hook" << endl;
        return;
    }

    MSG msg;
    while(!GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0) && this->active) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

LRESULT _mouse_hook_callback(int nCode, WPARAM event, LPARAM ptr_keyboard) {
    assert(thread_hook);
    auto consume = thread_hook->mouse_hook_callback(nCode, event, ptr_keyboard);
    if(consume)
        return 1;
    return CallNextHookEx(nullptr, nCode, event, ptr_keyboard);
}

bool KeyboardHook::mouse_hook_callback(int nCode, WPARAM event, LPARAM ptr_mouse) {
    MouseButtonEventEntry* mb_event;
    switch (event) {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            mb_event = allocate_mb_event();
            mb_event->type = KeyEvent::PRESS;
            mb_event->key = "MOUSE1";
            break;
        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            mb_event = allocate_mb_event();
            mb_event->type = KeyEvent::RELEASE;
            mb_event->key = "MOUSE1";
            break;

        case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
            mb_event = allocate_mb_event();
            mb_event->type = KeyEvent::PRESS;
            mb_event->key = "MOUSE3";
            break;
        case WM_RBUTTONUP:
            mb_event = allocate_mb_event();
            mb_event->type = KeyEvent::RELEASE;
            mb_event->key = "MOUSE3";
            break;

        case WM_XBUTTONDOWN: {
            auto mouse = (MouseHookStruct*) ptr_mouse;
            auto x_index = GET_XBUTTON_WPARAM(mouse->mouseData);

            mb_event = allocate_mb_event();
            mb_event->type = KeyEvent::PRESS;
            mb_event->key = "MOUSEX" + std::to_string(x_index);
            break;
        }
        case WM_XBUTTONUP: {
            auto mouse = (MouseHookStruct*) ptr_mouse;
            auto x_index = GET_XBUTTON_WPARAM(mouse->mouseData);

            mb_event = allocate_mb_event();
            mb_event->type = KeyEvent::RELEASE;
            mb_event->key = "MOUSEX" + std::to_string(x_index);
            break;
        }
        default:
            return false;
    }

    mb_event->next = nullptr;
    mb_event->hook = thread_hook;

    EnterCriticalSection(&global_event_dispatcher->mutex);
    *global_event_dispatcher->event_tail = mb_event;
    global_event_dispatcher->event_tail = &mb_event->next;

    /* notify other threads that some work needs to be done */
    WakeAllConditionVariable(&global_event_dispatcher->cv_work);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&global_event_dispatcher->mutex);
    return false;
}
```

Please note, even though `allocate_mb_event` may indicate otherwise, I'm not allocating any memory in this method at all. I just use a lock free bucket list in order to get the next `MouseButtonEventEntry` structure.

The locking of `global_event_dispatcher->mutex` isn't an issue either, only one other thread could ever lock this mutex. It sleeps on the condition variable and then only retrieves the next entries in the event queue when it gets notified via the cv.

### My issue

In general, this code works as intended ... except for some users.

Some users, especially the one who are playing games, experience a significant mouse lag/slow down.

As it turns out, it seems like the `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook itself is the issue.  Even without any significant event processing (e.g. empty method), they still experience it.

One approach of mine was to boost the dispatching thread priority class to `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS`, but it doesn't really help a lot.  I also measured the actual time spend within the callback and it was constantly way less than 1us.

So I don't actually think that the callback is the issue itself.

### What I'm looking for

I'm not sure if I'm just overlooking something, or if using the `WH_MOUSE_LL` callback isn't a good idea in general.

So, what would be an alternative to capture global mouse button events, or some way to improve the performance of the callback?

Comment: `while(!GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)...` seems wrong - the `!` in particular.

Comment: Why? From docs: `If the function retrieves the WM_QUIT message, the return value is zero.`. Else its blocking 'till a next event. The only other possibility in an invalid hwnid which is null in my case ;) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError [When will GetMessage return -1?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130322-00/?p=4873)

Comment: @WolverinDEV "*what would be an alternative to capture global mouse button event*" - you can use [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) instead. You just need an `HWND` for it to send `WM_INPUT` messages to, and you can use a [message-only window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows) for that ([What kind of messages can a message-only window receive?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171218-00/?p=97595)).

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's an interesting approach. I'll investigate that tomorrow, but it sounds promising ;) thanks for the grammar edit.

Comment: Okey thanks @RemyLebeau, your alternative works flawless ;)